# can't search classList .with contains

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to search `DOM` elements for a specific class using `classList.contains`, but getting this error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined."

I'm getting the same error when trying to use `.indexOf` to search. The part confusing me is that when I `console.log` this.classList, it logs the classList object correctly. Where am I going wrong in using contains? Note: this is a re-implementation of `getElementsByClassName` using recursion for practice.

```
var allNodes = document.body;

function comb(parent, callback) {
if (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
    for (var node = parent.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
        comb(node, callback);
    }
}
callback.call(parent);
}

function check() {
var passed = this.classList.contains("right");
if (passed) {
   return this.nodeValue;
}
}

comb(allNodes, check);
```

Comment: Have you made a Fiddle for this?

Comment: Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/joshturn/zLygvv6d/

Comment: You've lost the scope of the node, you need to bind it to the function call

Comment: That is a strange looking `for` loop

Comment: @adeneo: it is, I copied it from the MDN page on nodes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstChild` and `nextSibling` will include text nodes, which don't have a `classList`

You want to stick to elements, so inside the for loop, say:

```
for (var node = parent.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
  if (node.nodeType == 1)
    comb(node, callback);
  }
}
```

or, as noted by Omar in the comments:

```
for (var node = parent.firstElementChild; node; node = node.nextElementSibling) {
  comb(node, callback);
}
```

Comment: or you can use `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibling`

Comment: Or that. That would be better. :-)

Comment: insert obligatory IE warning about `nextElementSibling` here... also, `children[0]` is more compat than `firstElementChild`